# In Oracle SQL how can i find all values in one column for which in another column exist more than one distinct value

Tags: sql, oracle, distinct, oracle18c

I have an Oracle table like this

```
| id | code | info             | More cols |
|----|------|------------------|-----------|
| 1  | 13   | The Thirteen     | dggf      |
| 1  | 18   | The Eighteen     | ghdgffg   |
| 1  | 18   | The Eighteen     |           |
| 1  | 9    | The Nine         | ghdfgjgf  |
| 1  | 9    | Die Neun         | ghdfgjgf  |
| 1  | 75   | The Seventy-five | ghfgh     |
| 1  | 75   | The Seventy-five | ghfgh     |
| 1  | 2    | The Two          | ghfgh     |
| 1  | 27   | The Twenty-Seven |           |
| 1  | 27   | The Twenty-Seven |           |
| 1  | 27   | el  veintisiete  | fghfg     |
| .  | .    | .                | .         |
| .  | .    | .                | .         |
| .  | .    | .                | .         |
```

In this table I want to find all rows with values  in column `code` which have **more than one *distinct* value** in the `info` column. So from the listed rows this would be the values `9` and `27` and the associated rows.

I tried to construct a first query like

```
SELECT code FROM mytable
  WHERE COUNT(DISTINCT info) >1
```

but I get a "*ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here*" error. Also I don't know how to express the condition *`COUNT(DISTINCT info)` "with a fixed postcode"*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `having` with `group by` - `aggregate functions` don't work with `where clause`

```
SELECT code 
       FROM mytable
group by code
having COUNT(DISTINCT info) >1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write your query as:

```sql
SELECT code
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY code
HAVING MIN(info) <> MAX(info);
```

Writing the `HAVING` logic this ways leaves the query *sargable*, meaning that an index on `(code, info)` should be usable.

You could also do this using exists logic:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT code
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable WHERE t2.code = t1.code AND t2.info <> t1.info);
```